# New Xcode version 11.2.1 build app layout problem

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

When I update the Xcode to 11.2.1, then build the app have layout problem, like this.

[image: Build at Xcode 11.2.1]
This is the normal version:
[image: Build at Xcode 11.2.1 before]
How do I modify it?

Comment: use fullScreen property for modal VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to presenting `viewController` using below code.

**Swift:**

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Objective-c:**

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen ;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```