# View Controller status bar is overlapping in new iPhone like ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

View Controller status bar is overlapping in new iPhone like ios 8[image: Status Bar image] When it's redirecting to another view controller , existing view screen status bar is displaying partially. I am using this code to redirect

```
SecondView *view = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59085164/7851805

Comment: it is iOS 13 feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Xcode version 11.2.1 build app layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083062/new-xcode-version-11-2-1-build-app-layout-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not bug of status bar, this is feature of iOS 13, If you don't want this than you can set `modalPresentationStyle` to fullscreen. Like,

```
SecondView *view = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
view.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:NULL];
```